# Ruby: CLI script failing when requiring gems installed through git

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

I am patching a script, and want to run code from a repo I manage that has patches.

The gem in question is not installed through a published gem but through a github link

When requiring any gem that is **normally** installed. The script works. But requiring any gem that is installed through a github link fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show us relevant sections from your Gemfile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the issue was I was running the script in question using `./bin/path/script`

This will **not work** if the script includes github referenced gems, you need to prefix this with `bundle exec` which is not immediately obvious, given that when you use non-github referenced gems, it works fine without it.

Now running `bundle exec ./bin/path/script` will work for both, it's probably just better using that wherever possible.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the problem correctly, there are a few solutions:

- Clone the gem that's only available via the github link, build the gem locally, install it. You should be able to require it
- You might be able to manage the project with `bundler` and a `Gemfile`. Instructions [here](https://bundler.io/guides/git.html) for the syntax. Bundler basically does what I suggested above, for you. I don't think `gem` can install a gem from a remote natively?

Would love to see some more clarification, and if you're using a Gemfile the relevant snippets

Comment: As mentioned, I am doing that.